# How can I use filter operator of rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have some code, where I have observable. I want to change array filter method to filter of rxjs. How can I use filter operator of rxjs?

```
@Input() public articleTags: Observable<ALArticleTag[]>;
public selectedArticleTags: ALArticleTag[] = [];
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.articleTags.pipe(
            take(1),
            map(tags =>  {
                return this.selectedArticleTags = this.article.tagIds ? tags.filter(tag => {
                    return this.article.tagIds.includes(tag.id);
                }) : [];
            }),
        ).subscribe(response => {
            this.selectedArticleTags = response;
            this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
        });
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to change to `filter` of rxjs?

Comment: because it's recommendation of my boss and I have to implement it

Comment: rxjs `filter` filters through items emitted by the source Observable, while the array `filter` filters through the elements in an array, two different things. You could make `articleTags` into an `Observable<ALArticleTag>` (not an array) and emit for each tag at the source instead of emitting one array, but then you have to remove the `take(1)` too

Comment: Why do you do `take(1)` in the first place? Does `articleTags` emit multiple values? How is `articleTags` defined in the components that use this component?

Comment: @prolina there is a way to do it, but I would seriously doubt you need that in this situation. tell your boss that the rxjs `filter` doesn't bring any benefit here, but only makes the implemention less intuitive

Comment: Your boss should be more interested in why this is subscribing and manually handling change detection instead of using async pipe and onpush change detection. And maybe why the child component is doing this instead of the parent which could instead pass in the unwrapped data to the child.

Answer (score 3):

Do take note that RxJS's [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator is quite different from JavaScript's native [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

RxJS's filter operator allows you to

> Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those
>   that satisfy a specified predicate.

In other words, the RxJS `filter` operator excludes observable from the stream that meets a certain condition, which is quite different from what `Array.filter()` does, which is to filter/remove objects or values from the array based on a certain condition.

For instance, the below sequence uses the RxJS `filter()` operator to filter out `tags` whose length are less than 1.

```
this.articleTags
  .pipe(
    filter(tags => tags.length > 1),
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do the rest
  })
```

Therefore, the resulting output when the observable values have been returned would be `articleTags` whose length is more than 1.

Hence, I don't think you should use the RxJS `filter` operator to replace the filtering operation within the `map()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you want to filter tags by if this condition is satisfied ***this.selectedArticleTags = this.article.tagIds*** and then you filter the array
by this condition ***tags.filter(tag => this.article.tagIds.includes(tag.id))***.

The code should look like this:

```
@Input() public articleTags: Observable<ALArticleTag[]>;
public selectedArticleTags: ALArticleTag[] = [];
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.articleTags.pipe(
            take(1),
            filter(tags => this.selectedArticleTags = this.article.tagIds),
            map(tags => tags.filter(tag => this.article.tagIds.includes(tag.id));
            }),
        ).subscribe(response => {
            this.selectedArticleTags = response;
            this.changeDetection.markForCheck();
        });
    }
```